# Submit a POST Form that is in iframe in other domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Assuming that website1.com/page_1.php has a form like this :

```
<form action="http://www.website1.com/action" method="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="sdfddgfg">
   <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1">
   <input type="submit" class="btn send" value="Send">
</form>
```

**And website2.com/page_2.php has iframe like that :**

```
<iframe src="http://www.website1.com/page_1.php"></iframe>
```

Using JQuery or JS ,How can I submit the form with id `myForm` without click when visiting `website2.com/page_2.php?`.

Comment: Do you have access to changing website1?  If not, you will most likely be out of luck due to very valid security reasons.

Comment: cross-domain "chatter" between a page and an iframe is possible, as long as you can access the source code for both - i.e. both pages will need modification

Comment: Take a look at the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: I think its similar your scenario..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446210/cross-domain-post-iframe

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this just in the HTML of your iframe (you don't need to do anything on the "parent" window:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="https://www.yoursite.com/" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="sdfddgfg">
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="btn send" value="Send">
  </form>
  <script>
    (function() {
      document.getElementById('myForm').submit()
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This just submits the form on load, and it doesn't solve the case.